# Using variables in polylang string translations

Tags: plugin-polylang

Using polylang I am using `pll_register_string()` and `pll__()` to translate and output.

I would like to use variables in the translated strings for use in templates. I can see that yoast SEO manages this using the syntax `%%variable%%`

How does this work (I can't find any documentation)?

Essentially I have a form  " prefix - output of WP function - suffix ". For instance "The Home Page" where "Home" is the result of  Wordpress function `the_title();`  I would like to translate this, so;

```
echo pll__('The'); the_title(); echo pll('Page');
```

How do I simplify this in the form

```
sprint_f ( pll__('The %%title%% Page'), get_the_title() );
```

I realise I am skirting over grammar differences !

Comment: it's better to use a phrase because in another language, that can be translated as "the page called %%title%%". [look this page for more examples](http://ottopress.com/2012/internationalization-youre-probably-doing-it-wrong/). now I have a question about your question : why don't you use `__(...` and the translation system available in the wordpress core ?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not entirely sure. I'm new to the concept of multi language sites. The only problem with a phrase is that this piece of code appears on a template used by 20 different pages with different values for %%title%%. But thanks for the link, I shall read and digest.

Comment: Thank you, that link made everything very clear indeed. 
I've started using .po files too instead of polylang strings,

Answer (score 1):

For those that may stumble on this, please first [read the link](http://ottopress.com/2012/internationalization-youre-probably-doing-it-wrong/) provided by @Kaperto

Which provided me with the syntax;

```
printf( _n('The %s page', 'The %s pages', $number, 'text-domain'), get_the_title() );
```

The examples in the link above cover most of what is needed when dealing with variables in translation strings